CakePHP5 - File size validation
This validation doesn't pass:
$validator
    ->requirePresence('file1', false)
    ->allowEmptyFile('file1')                       
    ->add('file1', [
        'maxSize' => [
            'rule' => ['fileSize', '<', '500kb'],
        ],
    ]);

Error message: The provided value is invalid
This validation passes:
$validator
    ->requirePresence('file1', false)
    ->allowEmptyFile('file1')                       
    ->add('file1', [
        'fileSize' => [
            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                $fileSize = $context['data']['file1']['size'];
                return $fileSize < 500000;
            },
        ],
    ]);

No error, validation is successful.
In the controller, when I print file1, it looks like this:
pr($this->request->getData('file1'));
exit;

[file1] => Array
    (
        [dirname] => W:\wamp64\www\webroot\img\frontend\about-infos/tmp\8cbc3a9b1bb5ad5e63010083df137b29
        [basename] => np_file_219829.jpg
        [extension] => jpg
        [filename] => np_file_219829
        [tmp_name] => W:\wamp64\www\webroot\img\frontend\about-infos/tmp\8cbc3a9b1bb5ad5e63010083df137b29\np_file_219829.jpg
        [error] => 0
        [name] => np_file_219829.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [size] => 232267
    )

Please help, what is the problem?

File upload arrays are not supported anymore, uploads should be instances of \Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface. You need to fix whatever is causing the use of the array style.
